# If somebody plays a wild card (without +4), is the next person's turn skipped?

Tags: uno

3 of us were playing Uno, and somebody layed down a regular wild card. I tried to play the next card because it was my turn, but everybody said that it skipped my turn. I don't believe it did. Please answer soon!

Comment: Do keep in mind that Uno is a heavily houseruled game. Just because the official rules say a wild does not skip doesn't mean they won't continue to play that way. If they decide that they should keep it as a rule regardless of what the official rules say, don't be surprised.

Answer (score 6):

No, it does not skip your turn. There is a separate card called “Skip” that does that, Wild only allows you to change the color being played.

From [the rules](https://service.mattel.com/instruction_sheets/42001pr.pdf):

> **Wild Card -** When you play this card, you may change the color being played to any color (including the current color) to continue play. You may play a Wild card even if you have another playable card in hand. If this card is turned up at the beginning of play, the person to the left of the dealer chooses the color to begin play and plays the first card.

Nothing about skipping a player is mentioned.